# Editing Header with a Page Builder

Tags: headers, custom-header

Is it possible to edit my site's header with a page-builder plugin, such as Page Builder, Elementor, or Gutenberg? I don't want to be stuck in the constraints of the theme and/or Wordpress's idea of how a header should be structured.

I essentially just want to define a block section either above and/or below the menu that appears on every site page.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this isn't possible without additional plugins/development. For instance, [Beaver Builder Header Footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bb-header-footer/) is a plugin that accomplishes this for the Beaver Builder page builder. And the [pro version of Elementor allows this](https://docs.elementor.com/article/335-create-headers-using-elementors-theme-builder). They both require compatible themes.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do it with elementor plugin but definitely it depends on your theme, if it won’t be optimized i don’t think it will work as expected when editing header/footer